# Drop off Library and Contetn Organizer Error SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, organizer

Getting an error when trying to upload files to Drop Of Librarry with two same file names. Versioning doesnt work if Content Organizer is working. In other librarys versionig is working, error only in DropOfLibrarry and only if Content Organizer is working. 
Found this error when type CANCEL after document uploading.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can escape this error ?

Comment: Duplicate Submissions doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Standart Versioning on DropOffLibrarry dont work if Content Organizer is turned on.

Version of SharePoint : SharePoint 2010 CLOUD.